# For some reason freb.xsl is not applied to a IIS Express TraceLogFile

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-express

I am debugging an ASP.NET MVC 4 application in IIS Express 7.5, but for some reason the *frNNNNNN.xml* that holds the trace for crucial request i need to debug **is not transformed** at all. Instead, plain text is displayed in IE9.

Other trace files are transforming and opening well using existing *freb.xsl*.

Did anyone have similar issue and know what's going on?

**EDIT:** I found out (by opening it in FF) that .xml does not get transformed due to parsing error:

```
XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
Location: file:///.../fr000066.xml
Line Number 7703, Column 23:  
<Data Name="Buffer">‹</Data>
--------------------^
```

But I still don't know why is it happening, and how to prevent it.

Comment: what is the trace xml file size? by any chance it's size is going beyond the default trace file max size limit and getting truncated?

Comment: No, xml is not truncated, it is just that those illegal characters appear.